# Access iframe's top html and body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following iFrame structure , I want to access the html and body tag of top html, so I can sroll view top in click of button inside iframe.

```
 <html>
     <body>
      <div>
        <iframe> 
          <html>
           <body>
                content
                <input>button</input>
           </body>
         </html>
        </iframe>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `top` object (which only works at the [same domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)):

```
var topDocument = top.document;
//do anything you want

//Example:
topDocument.documentElement; //Returns a reference to the HTML element
topDocument.body; //Returns a reference to the top's body
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the very first HTML element, use this:

```
$("html:first")
```

And if you need to access the other HTML element through the iframe you can use this: $("iframe").children("html")

```
$("iframe").children("html")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "top" keyword.
Like
`top.id.document` where id is the 'id' of any element in top html of iframe.
You need to access that from the source of iframe's html.